# Google Maps - Transparent line cutting off markers

Tags: javascript, maps, markers

I have a line cutting off my markers and I am totally lost, any idea of what could it be?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, without your code we're as lost as you are. Please add your relevant code that causes the issue to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of why this happened but I solved it by giving the map div a CSS attribute called box-sizing: initial.